# after mode: 'history' vue router doesn't work

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vuejs2

I started learning vuejs recently and build and app with firebase for authentication.
I got a problem after i installed the webpack theme and tried to remove the default hashtag on links. When i insert the `mode:history` it doesnt redirect me after i login to my hello page. When i remove it everything works fine.

My index.js (under my `router` folder):

```
Vue.use(Router)

const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '*',
      redirect: '/login'
    },
    {
      path: '/',
      redirect: '/login'
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'Login',
      component: Login
    },
    {
      path: '/sign-up',
      name: 'SignUp',
      component: SignUp
    },
    {
      path: '/hello',
      name: 'Hello',
      component: Hello,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      }
    }
  ]
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  let currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  let requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth);

  if (requiresAuth && !currentUser) next('login')
  else if (!requiresAuth && currentUser) next('hello')
  else next()
})

export default router
```

And here is a sample of my login button:

```
<button class="btn" type="submit" v-on:click="signIn">Log In</button>
```

And my component script:

```
<script>
  import firebase from 'firebase'

  export default {
    name: 'login',
    data: function() {
      return {
        email: '',
        password: ''
      }
    },
    methods: {
      signIn: function() {
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password).then(
          (user) => {
            this.$router.replace('hello')
          },
          (err) => {
            alert('Oops. ' + err.message)
          }
        );
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Does this have something to do with the `v-on:click` function ?

Pls let me know if you need anything else for solving my issue.

Comment: No its fine, like i mentioned earlier when i remove the history mode everything just works fine

Comment: Please show your entire template code

Answer (score 0):

Case matters!

Replace

```
this.$router.replace('hello')
```

with

```
this.$router.replace('Hello')
```

Also replace

```
next('login')
```

with

```
next('/login')
```

or

```
next('Login')
```

Comment: where should i put `next('/login')`  ?

Comment: here `if (requiresAuth && !currentUser) next('login')` and next line as well

Comment: I updated the answer. You need to call the route explicitly by its name or path. Case matters.

Comment: Did you change all instances? like next('hello')

Comment: Also, you should use .push instead of .replace in a login instance. If the user clicks the back button, they want to go back to the login page and not to whatever was before that. Generally 'replace' is not a great user experience in most contexts.

Comment: @fortheNAme yeas, stil not woring, tried also with this.$router.push('Hello')

Comment: @fortheName Does this have something to do with the v-on:click function ?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the signin function. You should put in console.logs and find where its having a problem. For example, is it hitting the router? You can put in a console.log(from) in the beforeEach to see if that is getting hit.

Comment: This isn't helping :/